# HTTP 408 - The time allowed for the login process has been exceeded. j_security_check

Tags: forms, cookies, j-security-check

Here is the sequence of events:

1.From a JSP page a form is submitted to an IdP login page:

```
<form action="http://xxx" method="POST">
  <input type="hidden" name="idp" id="idp" value="yyy">
  <input type="submit" value="Login">
</form>
```

2.After login, the user gets redirected back to a page that says authenticated.

3.From that page, a form is automatically submitted to login the user into another site:

```
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function bodyOnloadHandler() {
      document.forms[0].submit();}
  </script>
</head>
<body onload="bodyOnloadHandler()">    
  <form action="/ccc/j_security_check" method="GET">
    <input name="j_username" value="aaa" type="hidden">
    <input name="j_password" value="bbb" type="hidden">        
  </form>
</body>
```

4.This brings up the correct URL and it works when browsing manually, but now I get the following error:

State HTTP 408 - The time allowed for the login process has been exceeded. If you wish to continue you must either click back twice and re-click the link you requested or close and re-open your browser.

Comment: Seems it has something to do with session expiry. Source: Vimal Bera.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will probably not be very helpful, but I found out what the problem was. There was a watchdog service that did not get a response, and kept on restarting Tomcat. It was not easy to notice this - Thanks Etienne.